# Are the rational numbers isomorphic to $\Bbb Z/(p\Bbb Z)$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

> Are the rational numbers isomorphic to $\Bbb Z/(p\Bbb Z)$?

Is this state the above statement true? If so, can someone explain the proof for this? I'm having a hard time wrapping my mind around this.

Comment: There are infinitely many rationals. $Z/pZ$ is a finite set. So the two can't be isomorphic. What made you think they might be?

Comment: In addition, adding $1$ to itself $p$ times yields $p$ in the rational numbers and yields $0$ in $\mathbb Z/p\mathbb Z$. So this is another reason for why they cannot be the same.

Comment: I'm reading some notes on fields and I came across a line: Note that the prime subfield of F is isomorphic to either Q or Z/pZ.

I'm assuming that prime subfields are isomorphic to either one or the other, but not both at once then.

Comment: @qqmuffin If $F$ is a field (or any integral domain) then look at its subring generated by $1_F$ : it is (isomorphic to) $\mathbb{Z}$ or $\mathbb{Z}/n \mathbb{Z}$ (in the latter case $n = p$ is prime since $F$ is an integral domain). And the subfield of $F$ generated by $1_F$ (the smallest subfield) is then $\mathbb{Q}$ or $\mathbb{Z}/p \mathbb{Z}$

Answer (score 0):

No. $|\Bbb Z/(p\Bbb Z)|=p$ yet $|\Bbb Q|=\infty$.